# Pandas merging several dfs date format error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime-format

**The purpose of this code:**

1. Scrape a bunch of tables via Pandas and Beautiful Soup.
2. Concatenate this tables into a single data frame.

The code works fine for the first step. But it is not working in the second.

And the problem is the date time format. In fact, I have two date formats

- 2018-09-24 01:30:00
- Sep 09, 2018 (Aug) 21:30

And I don’t get it how this happened after parsing the date, I mean how a function gives me two different formats of dates, any way…..

**Here is the code:**

```
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 " "Safari/537.36", "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}
url = open(r"C:\Users\Sayed\Desktop\script\sample.txt").readlines()

dfs = []

for site in url:
    req = Request(site, headers=header)
    page = urlopen(req)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
    table = soup.find('table')
    df = pd.read_html(str(table), parse_dates={'DateTime': ['Release Date', 'Time']}, index_col=[0])[0]
    df = df.astype('unicode')
    df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])
    dfs.append(df)
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, join='outer').sort_index(ascending=False)
print(df)
```

**Here is the error:**

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:\Users\Sayed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3078, in get_loc

    return self._engine.get_loc(key)

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 'DateTime'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:/Projects/Tutorial/try.py", line 19, in <module>
    df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])

  File "C:\Users\Sayed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2688, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)

  File "C:\Users\Sayed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2695, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)

  File "C:\Users\Sayed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2489, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)

  File "C:\Users\Sayed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4115, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)

  File "C:\Users\Sayed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 'DateTime'
```

Comment: The fact that `KeyError` is being returned leads me to believe that one of the dataframes you're concatenating doesn't contain `DateTime`. Have you confirmed it's in each dataframe?

Comment: @StephenWitkowski i do and it return me that the DateTime column as an object